# Nokogiri: How to retrieve the text from an XML::Element, excluding the text from its descendants?

Tags: ruby, xpath, nokogiri

Is there a more elegant way to write the following code?

```
def get_text(element)
  text_node = element.children.find &:text?
  text_node.text if text_node
end
```

Comment: nokogori.org: `XML is like violence - if it doesn’t solve your problems, you are not using enough of it.` Just thought I'd mention this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can write

```
element.xpath('text()').to_s
```

which returns the raw text of text children of `element` excluding any text in descendant nodes (whereas your code only return the first text child of `element`).

Answer (score 0):

Remember that the DOM is hierarchical so you need to remove the child nodes:

Starting with this:

```
require 'nokogiri'

xml = <<EOT
<xml>
  <a>some text
    <b>
      <c>more text</c>
    </b>
  </a>
</xml>
EOT

doc = Nokogiri::XML(xml)
```

If you don't mind doing it destructively:

```
doc.at('b').remove
doc.text #=> "\n  some text\n    \n  \n"
```

If you do mind:

```
a_node = Nokogiri::XML.fragment(doc.at('a').to_xml)

a_node.at('b').remove
a_node.text #=> "some text\n    \n  "
```

Strip the trailing carriage returns and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

```
of course this syntax will also help you

==================================

doc = Nokogiri::Slop <<-EOXML
<employees>
  <employee status="active">
    <fullname>Dean Martin</fullname>
  </employee>
  <employee status="inactive">
    <fullname>Jerry Lewis</fullname>
  </employee>
</employees>
EOXML
====================================
# navigate!
doc.employees.employee.last.fullname.content # => "Jerry Lewis"

fullname = @doc.xpath("//character")
puts fullname.text
```